# Ubuntu Studio Cannot Mount External Drive

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd, nvme

Trying to mount USB NVMe M.2 box to laptop with Ubuntu Studio 20.04 to no avail.

Without the device connected:

```
$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
sda6
```

Wit the device connected:

```
$ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
sda6
sdb
```

So I try...

```
$ mkdir /media/usb
$ mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
mount: /media/usb: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist.

$ mount /dev/sdb /media/usb
mount: /media/usb: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.
```

Ironically the NVMe box only came with USB male to male cable and I took the USB cable from my mobile phone. USB port seems 3.0, but the cable runs on 2.1 speed. Interesting parts from **lshw**...

```
*-usb
     description: USB controller
     product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 14
     bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
     version: 31
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
     resources: irq:128 memory:94400000-9440ffff
   *-usbhost:0
        product: xHCI Host Controller
        vendor: Linux 5.11.0-25-lowlatency xhci-hcd
        physical id: 0
        bus info: usb@1
        logical name: usb1
        version: 5.11
        capabilities: usb-2.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb:0
           description: Mass storage device
           product: AXAGON USB M.2 NVMe box
           vendor: JMicron
           physical id: 1
           bus info: usb@1:1
           version: 2.07
           serial: DD56419883CF6
           capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi
           configuration: driver=uas maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

The NVMe box is running. It's indicator lights up when connected, The box is detected by lshw, the NVMe disk is detected on Windows 10 **with device manager**, but since the file system is ext4 (previous Ubuntu install on laptop was on it), it is not readable in drives list when browsing. That's fine and expected. The NVMe was first inside the laptop, but since I upgraded with a better one, thought to use this one as external disk. Not sure where I am wrong. The device is not visible when booting with Live-USB or when trying to install an OS. I will be buying the USB 3 cable to increase speed... Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any data in your device?

Comment: Yes. I just removed it from the laptop and want to connect it externally. The previous Ubuntu install is on it. There may be a few things I would like to check before I erase it, but... Can't even mount it.

Comment: I want to make sure the partition is not damaged. Can your run fdisk `/dev/sdb` and that will bring you to a shell. In that shell I need you to enter the command `p` and share the output here. That will show any existing partitions on the device

Comment: fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such file or directory

Comment: What about `fdisk -l`? Do you see anything that starts with /dev/sda? And please make sure device is plugged physically

Comment: Yes, I see, but /dev/sda is my HDD, which is on the laptop motherboard. I am trying to connect another NVMe with USB box. The laptop also has a NMVe on the motherboard and it is on /dev/nvme0n1p...

Answer (score 0):

Appears hardware problem. The USB NVMe box does not read SATA M2 SSDs. Only PCI-E.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1163897)

Comment: That is the answer. When I changed the SATA M2 SSD with PCIe SSD, the USB box worked. It was a hardware thing - compatibility issue.